# Make a frequency table of used numbers in Excel2013

Tags: frequency, excel-2013, logical-operators

I have in mind to make a frequency table of random inserted values in Excel

I have in mind that I have a column where there will be a count every time I type a number between 1-10 lets say. The next column will calculate the frequency.

So what I'm strugeling with is the first column, I guess that I have to use logic function and count. But how?

Any recomendation? tips, search words or link of where I can find usefull information to complete my task.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you want but I think at least 'close'. Label your column, select it and insert a PivotChart with `Label` for AXIS(CATEGORIES) and Count of Label for VALUES. Then enter whatever numbers you want in the labelled column and refresh the PivotTable.